# How to extract boolean values from json file?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am using jq parser to convert json to csv.

Input:

```
"abc":{
      "a_val":true
   },
"def":{
      "b_val":false
   },
"normaltext":{
      "c_val":"text_value"
   }
```

I am getting below output.

```
,,"text_value"
```

But my desire output is

```
"true", "false", "text_value"
```

or

```
true, false, text_value
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the `jq` command you are using

Comment: Can you be more specific? what are you using? what have you done?

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this subject. But I can tell you the code which i am using for json parsing.

cat <json file> | jq -r '[.abc.a_val, .def.b_val, .normaltext.c_val] | @csv'

Comment: I can parse other values but I am facing issues only Boolean values, may be as they does not contain double quote so my code unable extract those true/false values as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't work:

```
jq -r '[.abc.a_val, .def.b_val, .normaltext.c_val] | @csv' jsonfile
```

Then try this:

```
jq -r '[(.abc.a_val | tostring), (.def.b_val | tostring), .normaltext.c_val] | @csv' jsonfile
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The input as shown is not quite valid JSON.  The following assumes that surrounding braces have been added so as to produce valid JSON.
2. The following jq query produces the desired CSV:

```
[.abc.a_val, .def.b_val, .normaltext.c_val] | @csv
```

#### Typescript

```
$ jq -r '[.abc.a_val, .def.b_val, .normaltext.c_val] | @csv' input.json
true,false,"text_value"
```

Comment: I am unable to extract Boolean values.. I am getting this output -> ,,"text_value"